# ListView focus on the last item in the list? - Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Could someone tell me how to keep the `ListView` focus always on the last list item? Following the example of a conversation in WhatsApp, where when we send a message, the message that has just arrived is always focused ... or any similar solution?

What I look for is whenever something is inserted in the `ListView`, instead of the Give the option to go up to view the items below, I would like it to be the other way around. Always displaying the last item on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an example where you have two elements, a list view and a buttom for adding new elements.

This is my XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView x:Name="ListView" />
    <Button
        Grid.Row="1"
        Clicked="Button_OnClicked"
        Text="Add animal" />
</Grid>
```

As you can see the button is very huge in order to show better the scroll.

In my Code-behind, I use `ListView.ScrollTo` method to scroll to the last added element, with animation:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private ObservableCollection<String> animals;
    private int _counter = 0;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        animals = new ObservableCollection<string>(new List<string>{"dog","cat","fish","elephant","monkey"});
        ListView.ItemsSource = animals;
    }

    private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var newElement = "new animal"+_counter;
        _counter++;
        animals.Add(newElement);
        ListView.ScrollTo(newElement, ScrollToPosition.End, true);
    }
}
```

I hope that this can help you.

Comment: Thank you my friend! Success! worked perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found this worked OK for me:

```
lv_items.ScrollTo(lv_items.ItemsSource.Cast<YourItemsSourceType>().Last(), ScrollToPosition.End, false);
```